# PHP: How to store and access a mysql query results in an object?

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP in general and seem to have stumped myself and was hoping someone could help me with this question...

Say I have a list of boat manufactures stored in a mysql table with the two columns id, boat_manufacturer.

Now I have a list of users and each user can have many boats.

How would I query,store and access that list of boats a particular user owns in an object of $user-> ?

Thanks for any help!

Chris Edwards

Comment: You should show your tries

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a classic relational DB here are your tables:

- boat_manufacturer (id, name, description)
- boat (id, name, manufacturer_id)
- user(id, name)
- purchases(id, user_id, boat_id)
  "User" class should have methods like "get_purchased_boats()", that has queries in it (if you are not using some framework with built-in functions like retrieving data from DB and models connections).
  To query these you need to use JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

[refer this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("-- your query here -- ");
while ($user = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $user->user_id;
    echo $row->boat_manufacturer;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```